# Is it possible to disable Junk Mail filtering in mail.app?

Tags: mail.app

I'm using Mail.app to sync three email accounts on my Mac. I find that usually my Junk Email is usually filled with a lot of emails. It is possible to disable this tab entirely ?

Comment: Are they all always Junk? If not, how would you find a good one & move it back?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't want a junk classification. I just want all my emails listed regularly and option to move to trash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want no filtering & wish to sort mail manually you can just disable Junk filtering altogether from Mail Prefs…

[image]

*Note:* That doesn't actually appear to delete the Junk folder - but it does stop it being populated at all.